# Suricata 6.x not decoding MPLS packets

Tags: suricata

Manuals say modern Suricata supports decoding **GRE/MPLS**/etc by default. My config file uses all the CPU cores with normal traffic. However, during analyzing MPLS traffic only 1 core is 100% busy and all other are only 0-1% . `stats.log` rows with **mpls** show `0` everywhere, no drops also. I tried playing with `set-cpu-affinity` setting, but nothing has changed.

`ifconfig` shows that incoming traffic is huge, so there is definitely something to analyze. Suricata was installed from recommended repo.

So it seems, that MPLS decoding is not working as expected or not working at all. Please explain what do I need to configure to start decoding/analyzing MPLS packets properly?

Comment: This seems like a highly product-focused question. Have you asked their support or their forums?

Comment: I also doubt that you will get an answer here, I also advise going to their forums or similar support options for help..